# Merge Function Fills Missing Row Names with Dates

Tags: r

I'm new to the community and to R as well, so apologies if any difficulties in reading the thread.

I am trying to combine two dataframes in R and my data output seems a bit strange.
The following is my code, where I am calling in two txt tables as dataframes, merging the two, filling in the "NA" as "0" and writing it to the table.

```
data.1=read.table("table1.txt",sep="\t",header=TRUE, row.names=1, as.is=T)
data.2=read.table("table2.txt",sep="\t",header=TRUE, row.names=1, as.is=T)

data_sum <- merge(x=data.1, y=data.2, by=0, all=TRUE)

data_sum[is.na(data_sum)] <- 0

write.table(data_sum, file = "table_out.txt", sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

Here, I'm understanding that:

1. data_sum should have the row names that from both of the files, and
2. table_out.txt should have filled in "NA" automatically where the
   value is missing from either table1.txt or table2.txt and replaced
   with 0.

However, R is automatically filling in the row names with random dates.
The following is an example of what is expected:

[image]

This an example of what is actually happening:

[image]

From running several tests, I think this is happening at the "merge" step, but I do not know why it is.

Any input on how this can be resolved will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Best,
Yehyun

Comment: Are you, by any chance, opening the output file in Excel to view and/or saving the original files in Excel? That seems like the kind of shenanigans Excel auto format does...

Comment: Yes, I am to manually rename the column names.. I just came across a paper published in Genome Biology where it states this issue. This is likely caused by Excel, or Office Libre, which automatically replaces the names of these rows to a date. Thanks for pointing it out. Now I know that Excel is the issue here.